# How can I convert the 3D Object designed in MAYA or 3D Max to OpenGL Object?

Tags: c++, opengl, c#

I'm try to convert the 3D Objects created in the Maya or 3D Max to Simple OpenGl object anyone please guide me how can I do so???

Comment: Choose just one language, or C++ or C#. They're different languages, so its methods to read data is too!

Comment: What is a "Simple OpenGl object"? What format are you trying to read from? This is a very poorly specified question overall.

Answer (score 2):

I think Assimp is what you are looking for( https://github.com/assimp/assimp ). There are some good tutorials out there if you head over to lighthouse3d ( http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/ ). It uses the new Core profile so it's as future safe as anything you will find. The tutorial is in C++ but it should be hard to port to C# if that's really what you want to use. Also, there is a C# wrapper of Assimp in the repo with it^_^
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question so this will be a pretty general answer. Don't think of it as exporting to OpenGL; instead you export from a 3D art tool to some file format and then write code to read that file format. So for example you can export to OBJ and then write code that reads in all the vertices from an OBJ file and puts that data into arrays for using with OpenGL.

You can find file format descriptions for most of the commonly used 3D file formats. For example, here's an explanation of OBJ file format:
http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/docs/brief-obj-file-format.html